# Joining 2 bar columns in barcharts with curved line

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have below `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
data = rbind(data.frame('val' = c(10, 30, 15), 'name' = c('A', 'B', 'C'), group = 'gr1'), data.frame('val' = c(30, 40, 12), 'name' = c('A', 'B', 'C'), group = 'gr2'))
ggplot(data,                         # Draw barplot with grouping & stacking
       aes(x = group,
           y = val,
           fill = name)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "stack", width = .1)
```

With this, I am getting below plot

[image]

However, I want to connect these bars with a curved area where the area would be equal to the value of the corresponding bar-component. A close example could be like,

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this with `ggplot`?

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something like an *alluvial plot*. There are various extension packages that could help you create such a plot, but it is possible to do it in ggplot directly using a bit of data manipulation.

```r
library(tidyverse)

alluvia <- data %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(x = seq(1, 2, 0.01),
            val = pnorm(x, 1.5, 0.15) * diff(val) + first(val))

ggplot(data,                        
       aes(x = as.numeric(factor(group)),
           y = val,
           fill = name)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",
             position = "stack", width = .1) +
  geom_area(data = alluvia, aes(x = x), position = "stack", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:2, labels = levels(factor(data$group)),
                     name = "Group", expand = c(0.25, 0.25)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  theme_light(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

A more generalized solution for more than 2 groups would be

```r
library(tidyverse)

alluvia <- data %>%
  mutate(group = as.numeric(factor(group)),
         name = factor(name)) %>%
  arrange(group) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(next_group = lead(group),
         next_val = lead(val)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(next_val)) %>%
  group_by(name, group) %>%
  summarise(x = seq(group + 0.01, next_group - 0.01, 0.01),
            val = (next_val - val) * pnorm(x, group + 0.5, 0.15) + val)

ggplot(data,                        
       aes(x = as.numeric(factor(group)),
           y = val,
           fill = name)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",
             position = "stack", width = .1) +
  geom_area(data = alluvia, aes(x = x), position = "stack", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(length(unique(data$group))), 
                     labels = levels(factor(data$group)),
                     name = "Group", expand = c(0.25, 0.25)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  theme_light(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome. Exactly what I wanted. Is it possible to generalise this with multiple  `group`? For example, when I tried with `data = rbind(data.frame('val' = c(10, 30, 15), 'name' = c('A', 'B', 'C'), group = 'gr1'), data.frame('val' = c(30, 40, 12), 'name' = c('A', 'B', 'C'), group = 'gr2'), data.frame('val' = c(10, 30, 15), 'name' = c('A', 'B', 'C'), group = 'gr3'))` it fails